# A variable becomes undefined after referencing it in a defun

Tags: common-lisp

Hello good people of stackoverflow, I am having a weird problem while following [Adam Peterson's Lisp for the Web tutorial](http://www.adampetersen.se/articles/lispweb.htm). The problem in question is probably a problem with Clozure CL, however I just wanted to provide some background.

What's happening is simple. I declare the variable *games* by doing (defvar *games* '()). When I declare a function that references this variable, such as game-from-name, the compiler just yells at me undeclared free variable *games*.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Please show the code of the function. Are these in separate source files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could be executing in a different package. Try examining the value of the `*in-package*` variable at the points where you define and access the variable to check which package is current. You use the `in-package` macro to set the current package.